# Criação de variável através da resposta do usuário em Python

Tags: python, variáveis

Gostaria de fazer que o usuário inserisse uma resposta de dessa resposta criaria uma "variável" ou não. Não sei se criação de uma nova variável seria a melhor forma, segue exemplo:

```
a = str(input('Existe mais produtos para serem adicionados?: '))
```

Nessa parte o usuário responderia *sim* ou *não*, se a resposta fosse *sim*, o programa criaria outra variável que receberia um determinado valor `float` (a2 a3 a4) e assim em seguida.

Comment: Infelizmente o que você está a procura no código não faz muito sentido. O que iria fazer com essas tais variáveis `a2 a3 a4` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu recomendária que você usasse dicionários. Assim você pode rastrear o valor pelo nome do item, por exemplo. Se você quisesse que rodasse um while até que não existisse mais produtos para serem adicionados, bastaria utilizar o seguinte código.

```
 #criamos nosso dicionario
d={}
a = "s"
#utilizei o lower pra sempre deixar a resposta em minusculo, pra nao ter problemas com input maiusculo
while a.lower() == "s":
    item = input("Digite o item que deseja adicionar")
    valor = float(input ("Digite o valor do item %s: "%item))
    d[item] = valor
    a = input ("Deseja adicionar mais algum item? s/n")
#para exibir em for, utilizamos a seguinte sintaxe
for x in d:
    #como o x vai rodar sempre com o valor da chave (nome), podemos chamar o valor do preço com a o dicionario[x] (d[x])
    print ("Item: %s \tPreço: %.2f"%(x, d[x]))
```

Answer (score 1):

O usuário criar não é possível assim. Mas aqui tenho uma solução

```
a= str (input ('Existe mais produtos para serem adicionados?: '))
a2 = 0
a3 = 0
a4 = 0
if a == 'sim':
    a2 = 1
else:
    a3 = 1
```

Mas, imagino que o melhor no seu código, seria uma lista.
Algo nesse gênero:

```
lista = []
a= str (input ('Existe mais produtos para serem adicionados?: '))
if a == 'sim':
   lista.append(1) #valor
```

Assim, o se você colocar dentro de um while, mudando o que você coloca dentro do append, e mudando o if, você consegue fazer uma lista infinita, que acho que é o que você deseja, dai você roda o while, enquanto a resposta for diferente de 'nao'. Se precisar de ajuda em como fazer, deixe o código, ou especifique o que você quer, ficarei feliz em ajudar.